# I'm getting IndexError: list index out of range error in pandas when trying print a huge file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting IndexError: list index out of range error in pandas when trying print a huge file
here is the simple code.
store_inventory.csv has 1000+ lines of data, I believe I need to add a parameter to fix this error need help.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('store_inventory.csv', names=['StoreNumber', 'Store', 'Store_subnet', 'MDF_subnet'], sep=',', index_col=[0])
print(df.to_dict())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to help without seeing a sample of the dataset.
Did you try without the index_col=[0]?

Comment: Hey thank you, I have removed the header of the csv and executed, works well and good now.